# React child component that summarizes and displays info passed in props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React.  I have a component that displays a list of items in a table.  I need to add a second component that summarizes and displays some information about the items.

I pass the items list from the parent component to the summary using props:

```
// Parent component
<SummaryTable items={this.state.items} />
```

And then in `SummaryTable` I compute totals by category:

```
class SummaryTable extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {'categories': this.summarizeCategories(props.items)};
  this.renderRows = this.renderRows.bind(this);
}

componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  console.info(nextProps);
  console.info(nextState);
}

summarizeCategories(items) {
  var categories = new Map();
  items.forEach((item) => {
    if(categories.has(item.category)) {
      let total = categories.get(item.category);
      categories.set(item.category, total + item.amount);
    } else {
      categories.set(item.category, item.amount);
    }
  });
  return categories;
}

renderRows() {
  return this.state.categories.forEach((value, key) => (
    <tr>
      <td>{key}</td>
      <td>{value}</td>
    </tr>
  ));
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="SummaryTable">
      <table>
        {this.renderRows()}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

}
```

The problem with this code is that the `state` in `SummaryTable` does not get updated when `props.items` changes.

I thought I could use `componentWillUpdate` to `setState` after `props` changes, but that results in an infinite loop (since settings state causes `componentWillUpdate` to be called again).

What is the best way to handle this?  I suppose I could do the calculation in the parent component and pass it down.

Comment: if you want to update your state based on your incoming props the best place will be [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) where using setState or just modifying state wouldn't trigger a rerender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [componentWillReceiveProps()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) instead of componentWillUpdate().